# Automatically use subclass type in method signature

Tags: python, oop, casting, signature, type-safety

I have a parent class with many subclasses in Python 3. Currently, the hierarchy looks something like this:

```py
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, obj: "Parent"):
        pass

class Child1(Parent):    
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def check(cls, obj: Parent) -> "Child1":
        if cls == obj.__class__:
            return obj
        else:
            raise TypeError("Bad type received.")

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def check(cls, obj: Parent) -> "Child2":
        if cls == obj.__class__:
            return obj
        else:
            raise TypeError("Bad type received.")

... many more children here ...
```

And then there is another hierarchy that uses these classes:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class Runnable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self) -> Parent:
        pass

class Thing1(Runnable):
    def run(self) -> Parent:
        ... do a thing that produces a Child1 ...

class Thing2(Runnable):
    def run(self) -> Parent:
        ... do a thing that produces a Child2 ...
```

There are places where I call `Thing1.run()` and need to access its field `x`. Python allows this, but it is not type-safe. The purpose of `check()` is to be a kind of assert and cast, so that using `Child1.check(Thing.run()).x` is type-safe but can raise an error.

But as you can see, `Child1.check()` and `Child2.check()` have an identical implementation; the only thing that changes is their return type. I have many such child classes, so I have repeated implementations for no good reason. **Is there a way to write the following in actual Python, so that duplicating the implementations is no longer needed?**

```py
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, obj: Parent) -> cls:   # <--- This return type is not allowed in real Python
        if cls == obj.__class__:
            return obj
        else:
            raise TypeError("Bad type received.")
```

Comment: Are you talking about how you manage the type hinting?  If so, https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures shows how you can do it --  both with `TypeVar` and with the new `Self` type.

Comment: @mgilson This is exactly what I mean, yes. You can post an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3.10 and before, you can do something like:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

ParentType = TypeVar("ParentType", bound="Parent")

class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def check(cls: Type[ParentType], obj: Parent) -> ParentType:
        ...
```

Starting with Python 3.11, they are introducing the [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) type which can be used directly:

```
from typing import Self

class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, obj: Parent) -> Self:
        ...
```

See [PEP-673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures) for more information on `Self`.